# How to do a groupBy() for a single item from each group in Laravel ORM

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, orm, eloquent

I am trying to get a single item from each category. Here is my test table:

```
-----------------
| id | category |
-----------------
|  1 | image    |
-----------------
|  2 | link     |
-----------------
|  3 | image    |
-----------------
|  4 | link     |
-----------------
```

If I do `table('test')->groupBy('category')->get();`, the return value is this:

```
[{"id":1,"category":"image",
  "id":3,"category":"image",
  "id":2,"category":"link",
  "id":4,"category":"link"}]
```

And if I do `table('test')->groupBy('category')->first();`, the return is:

```
[{"id":1,"category":"image"}]
```

But what I want is a **single item from each category**, like this:

```
[{"id":1,"category":"image",
  "id":3,"category":"link"}]
```

How do I achieve this? (I want to avoid looping as my table can get quite big - many categories). Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test::groupBy('category')->get();  of course it will retrieve single record of each category.

check whether the model name is test and table name is tests, I want to say follow
laravel convention.

Comment: oops, I had `Test::all()->groupBy('category')->get()`.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

```
$cat = DB::table('test')->select('id''category')
            ->groupBy('category')
            ->get();
```

then try `dd($cat)` you will get output what you need :)